# Guardar dados de Notificação

Tags: android

Estou a tentar implementar uma `Notification` diária. A hora dessa `Notification` é escolhida pelo usuário através de um `TimePicker` que aparece ao clicar num `LinearLayout` constituído por 2 `TextViews` em que num deles aparece a hora que o user escolheu. Tudo isto já está implementado sem problemas. O meu problema é quando saio da aplicação, a hora escolhida perde-se.

A única solução que vejo é guardar em Base de Dados esse dado e quando voltar a entrar, ir ler o que tenho guardado.
Existe alguma outra forma de fazer isto sem ter de recorrer a uma Base de Dados?

Comment: Uma forma possível e talvez a mais indicada para este caso será usar *SharedPreferences*. Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70392/2541) para um exemplo.

Comment: @ramaral obrigada, vou investigar.

Comment: @ramaral, se quiseres responde, q eu aceito a resposta. Funcionou! :)

Comment: Não há necessidade. No entanto se a resposta que te indiquei te foi útil podes votar nela, se assim o entenderes.